# Supervisord not closing http ports

Tags: python, supervisord

I'm trying to use Supervisord to keep my node.js web app alive.

However when I run supervisorctl shutdown, it doesn't close the http port that node.js uses.

Is there a way to configure Supervisord to shut down a process and close the port so I can restart webservers successfully?

```
[program:stream3]
command=<mycommand>
autostart=true
port=127.0.0.1:<myport>
autorestart=true
startretries=3
```